# I2S出力ができない

Tags: spresense

setPlayerModeでAS_SETPLAYER_OUTPUTDEVICE_I2SOUTPUTとしていますがI2S出力されません。
ライブラリも最新にしています。考えられる原因は何でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

ソースコードを見たところ、どうやら、

setPlayerModeでの
AsActivatePlayerParam::output_device

は、使っていないようです。

確認したところ、

InitOutputSelect の
InitOutputSelectParam::output_device_sel

に

AS_OUT_I2S

を入れることで、変更できました。

ご参考になれば。

Answer (score 0):

SPRESENSE が I2S のスレーブモードになっているためではないでしょうか？ 例えば、Raspberry Pi はマスタークロック出力がないので、通常マスター動作（マスタークロックを出力）する DAC が使われます。こちらの記事が詳しいです。（記事中にもありますが、マスターモードの DAC のほうがジッタが少なく高音質が期待できます）

https://blog.bnikka.com/audio/raspi-dac.html

SPRESENSE も マスターモード対応の DAC が使用されることを想定して、スレーブモードとなっている可能性があります。ただ、私もまだ試していないので、もし外していたらごめんなさい。